# How to get promise result using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

The following is the controller used to retrieve information from sharepoint. I can see debugging that the entry `data.d.UserProfileProperties.results[115].Value` has a property value that I need to render in view. How can I get that value from the result promise?

```
(function() {
    'use strict'
    var createPurchasingCardController = function($scope, $rootScope, $filter, $window, $location, $timeout, requestService) {        

        $scope.actionTitle = "";
        $scope.counter = [];                      

        var getCurrentUserData = function () {

            var dfd = new $.Deferred();
            var queryUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties";
            $.ajax({
                url: queryUrl,
                method: "GET",
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
                success: onSuccess,
                error: onError,
                cache: false
            });

            function onSuccess(data) {            
                dfd.resolve(data);                    
            }

            function onError(data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
                dfd.reject(errorMessage);
            }

            return dfd.promise();               
        }            

        var _init = function () {                
            $scope.counter = getCurrentUserData();
            console.log($scope.counter);
        }

        _init();

    }

    angular.module('myApp').controller('createPurchasingCardController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$filter', '$window', '$location', '$timeout', 'requestService', createPurchasingCardController]);
}());
```

I have tried to get it into the counter but it is not showing up. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should use the Angularjs [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using jQuery `.ajax`, use the $http service:

```
function getCurrentUserData() {
    var queryUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties";
    var promise = $http({
        url: queryUrl,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        cache: false
    }).then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
    }).catch(function(response) {
        console.log("ERROR", response);
        throw response;
    });

    return promise;               
}
```

Then extract the data from the returned promise:

```
function _init() {                
    var promise = getCurrentUserData();

    promise.then(function(data) {
        $scope.counter = data;
        console.log($scope.counter);
    });     
}

_init();
```

The promises returned by the $http service are integrated with the AngularJS framework. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $http Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#$http-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

assign your response object to `$scope` object

```
function onSuccess(data) {            
    $scope.promiseData = data
    dfd.resolve(data);                    
}
```